# Getting the most basic ajax working on xampp on windows 7 to check for internet connectivity

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, xampp

Before submitting a form `onclick="return check_internet_conn()"` is called to see if there is an internet connection, (I will be doing this on a mobile device, xampp will be on mobile device too. My testing happens on windows 7), this will request `check_internet_connection.php` file to check internet connection (prefer not to check to see if an image exists on some server to check for internet connectivity via javascript). `check_internet_connection.php` works fine but I can never get javascript ajax, jQuery ajax, nor javascript fetch(), return the file content.

```
<div class="container">
  <form action="processQuestion.php" method="post">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="question">Write your question here:</label>
     <textarea class="form-control" rows="7" id="question_txt" name="question"></textarea>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return check_internet_conn()">Submit Question</button> 
  </form>
  <p id="submit_error_no_internet" class="warning"></p>
</div>
```

Here is the PHP file

```
<?PHP

try {
@   $connected = fsockopen("www.example.com", 80);
    if ($connected) {
        fclose($connected);
        echo "Connected";
    }
}   

catch(Exception $e) {
  echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}

finally {
  echo "Not Connected!";
}

?>
```

And here are the three different attempts at ajax and js fetch(), with debugging additions.

```
<script src="jquery/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-4.5.3-dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script>

function check_internet_conn() {
    $.get("http://localhost/crud/check_internet_connection.php", function(data, status){
            switch(data) {
            case "Not Connected!":
                document.getElementById("submit_error_no_internet").innerHTML = "No Internet connection, connect to internet.";
                return false;
                break;
            case "ConnectedNot Connected!":
                return true;
                break;
            default:
                document.getElementById("submit_error_no_internet").innerHTML = "Nothing works";
            } 
        });
}

function check_internet_conn() {

    async function getText(file) {
        let myObject = await fetch(file);
        let myText = await myObject.text();
        switch(myText) {
        case "Not Connected!":
            document.getElementById("submit_error_no_internet").innerHTML = "No Internet connection, connect to internet.";
            return false;
            break;
        case "ConnectedNot Connected!":
            return true;
            break;
        default:
            document.getElementById("submit_error_no_internet").innerHTML = "Nothing works";
        }
    }

  getText("http://localhost/crud/check_internet_connection.php");
  
}


function check_internet_conn() {

    var myXmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    myXmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("submit_error_no_internet").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        switch(this.responseText) {
            case "Not Connected!":
                document.getElementById("submit_error_no_internet").innerHTML = "No Internet connection, connect to internet.";
                return false;
                break;
            case "ConnectedNot Connected!":
                return true;
                break;
            default:
                document.getElementById("submit_error_no_internet").innerHTML = "Nothing works";
        } 
      }
    };
    myXmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/crud/check_internet_connection.php");
    myXmlhttp.send();
    document.getElementById("submit_error_no_internet").innerHTML = myXmlhttp.status + " " + myXmlhttp.readyState;
}

</script>
```

I have attempted debugging in Firefox and Chrome, without much success. No error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like:

```html
<button onclick="checkConnection()">Check connection</button>
```

```js
function checkConnection() {
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
      url: "yourUrl",
      success: function(result) {
          if(result) {
          // you are connected
          } else {
          // you are not connected
          }
      },
      error: function(error) {
          // do something sad
      }
  });
});
```

```php
function is_connected() {
$connected = @fsockopen("www.example.com", 80); 
if ($connected){
    $is_conn = true; //action when connected
    fclose($connected);
}else{
    $is_conn = false; //action in connection failure
}
echo($is_conn);
die();
}
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested. I always get the error case, it never succeeds.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested, thank you. I also took out the button out of the form to prevent executing the form action. The ajax call always fails, which means I can't find out if there is an internet connection. I also want to return a value to prevent the form from being submitted if there is no internet connection,(is another way of doing this?) The php file instantly shows the correct result in the browser without a problem, when I call it directly.

Comment: I spent a good hour debugging in Chrome. I had to figure out where the actual result I was looking for is found, so here is the success function call: `success: function(jqXHR,result) {
 alert(jqXHR);
 switch(jqXHR){`